# Interstitial ads doesn't show on real device

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

I just created a new project and first thing that I implemented is Interstitial ad , I imported Admob into dependency like this `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'` and after that in Android Manifest I adde my app id like this

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="My App Id"/>
```

and now I created Interstitial ad I imported my add unit and it doesn't work properly , it shows test ads on the left side like this [image] and when I build an apk and try to install it on a real device it doesn't show at all , so this is my interstitial code

```
   private void launchInter() {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("interstitialadunit");

        //set the adListener
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                showAdInter();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                String message = String.format("onAdFailedToLoad (%s)", getErrorReason(errorCode));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                if (exitApp)
                    finish();
            }

        });
    }

    private void showAdInter() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("", "Intersitial ad was not ready to be shown");
        }
    }

    public void loadInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("")
                .build();

        //Lad the interstitial aa
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    //Get string errror reason from ad error
    private String getErrorReason(int errorCode) {
        String errorReason = "";
        switch (errorCode) {
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                errorReason = "Internal Error";
                break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST:
                errorReason = "Invalid Request";
                break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR:
                errorReason = "Network Error";
                break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:
                errorReason = "No fill";
                break;
        }
        return errorReason;
    }
```

and onCreate Method I call it like this

```
 launchInter();
    loadInterstitial();
```

what am I doing wrong, please help,if you need more information please let me know

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I get this  `W/Ads: JS: A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190306/r20110914/abg_lite.js,`